# tkinter: Scrollbar bar widget with resizable handle

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a widget usable in Python with tkinter, which is a scrollbar with resizable slider? This makes sense e.g. when displaying something in graphical format to pan (moving the slider) and zoom (resizing the slider) with the same widget.

In a waveform viewer from Cadence it looks like this:

[image: scrollbar with resizable handle]

You can resize the handle using the little triangles or just grabbing the left or right edge of the handle with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing like that in tkinter. Tkinter provides the basic building blocks, however. You could probably craft one using frames or a canvas.